# Trying to obfuscate my project using Crypto broke it

Tags: c#, .net, obfuscation

I was tyring to go through different obfuscating options that I have and in order to do it, I first tried my hands on Crypto.

here are the steps that I followed:

1. Open Cypto wizard and selected some options.
2. Select my solution file.

Finished the wizard and what I saw was that there were some of the Dlls well obfuscated BUT my project does not build now. Two things I noticed is that there is this weird .OBPROJ file in my folder and that is responsible for deleting all my old assemblies and then obfuscating them later.

I am seeing following error for 4 of my 18 projects which are failing to build:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: File 'C:\Dropbox\CPTFramework_old\CommonLib\obj\Debug\CommonLib.dll' not found.
```

Something very similar for all the 4 projects that are failing. Now, I am not sure what it did to the dll files in OBj/Debug folder but files are absolutely not there.

The other thing that I noticed is that all the projects, when build individually, do build fine. So there is definitely something wrong that has happened to my solution file. But I am not able to find out what exactly has changed.

Comment: commonlib.pdb is there but commonlib.dll is not there...

Comment: One more thing that I noticed was that when I manually copied all these missing assemblies from Bin to Obj folder and then did a build again, I saw the same errors. Also when I browsed to the folders, the files are gone now.

Comment: Has you ever resolved this? I have the same issue.

Comment: @LewisHarvey: I am sorry. Unfortunately I did not work further on this because of the kind of problems it was giving. I moved on to other obfuscation solutions and also not help form StackOverflow on this issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had this same issue recently and so, although outdated, here is the answer for anyone else.

It is related to your build order. I found that the build order in VS did not always correspond to the actual build order. I suggest looking through the output window after a failed build and see which projects are built first and last (you need these to configure Crypto). Obviously, don't forget to ignore any projects that are setup projects or projects not being built in release mode.

All that is required, is to reconfigure crypto with the correct first and last projects, reload your solution and it will build.

Answer (score 4):

Had similar issue.  After lot of struggle, found the solution.

In a multi core processor, VS will run the build parallely which makes the Cyrpto obfuscator run before the last project build completion.

**Making Maximum number of parallel project builds to 1** in VS 2013 will fix this issue.

TOOLS - Options.. - Build and Run

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the error happens when

1: you have once specified a project to be first or last and in your solution this isn't or is no longer the case. 
2: you have a dependency too something like Newtonsoft.Json

**case 1:**
I happened to run into the same issue when adding a dependency on an "as previous startup specified" project. I ran the wizard again then had 2 projects flagged as first...

What also happens is that you use the same shared dll in several projects wherein one it is the first and in the other it inst the first, you then start having to manually update the project depending on what you compile.

Ideally, the need for setting first or last should not be needed as the build order is already in the solution but I do not work at LogicNP...

To fix the issue look at the file's complaining in the output of VS as that's the one that is likely to have the false "first" flag.

Then Right-Click the project and select "Unload project" from the pop-up. Now again Right-click on the unloaded project and select Edit ; or open the .csproj file in a text editor.

Scroll to the bottom of the file and look for text that looks like this...
    
    False
    False
    Release|AnyCPU
        ..\CATS.Settings_Release_AnyCPU.obproj

Have a look at the CO_FirstProject and CO_LastProject tags and make sure that they are having the proper True and False option as the "wizard" doesn't update the current configurations.

One more note, it also creates a brand new crypto file, all of the old settings are gone....

**case 2:**
You have a dependency on something like the Newtonsoft.Json.dll, what you do is 1. copy that dll to a safe non-build-related location. 
2. link the dll in the output settings tab to the proper main assembly by
a. Selecting it from the list of "Embedded dependant assemblies in the following main assembly"
b. Now Click Additional dependencies/files  and add the file
[image: Now you should have something like this]
If find more cases where I can't compile I will update the post, or contact me as it can be extremely frustrating to find errors like this...

Answer (score 0):

I just get the same issue, here is my answer based on the Crypto help documentation, it totally removes your solution dependency to Crypto by suppressing its MSBuild integration.

- Edit the csproj/vbproj files of the first and last project selected when you run the Crypto wizard : remove all the content between the 
  `<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == '....'">`  and  `<Import Project="..." />`
  (inclusive) towards the end of the project files.

So in my case I removed in my first project :

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <CO_FirstProject>True</CO_FirstProject>
    <CO_LastProject>False</CO_LastProject>
    <CO_Config>Release|AnyCPU</CO_Config>
    <CO_ProjectFilePath>..\.."ALL MY DLL/EXE HERE"
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="C:\Program Files (x86)\LogicNP Software\Crypto Obfuscator For .Net 2015\CryptoObfuscator.targets" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == '....' ">
```

and in my last:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <CO_FirstProject>False</CO_FirstProject>
    <CO_LastProject>True</CO_LastProject>
    <CO_Config>Release|AnyCPU</CO_Config>
    <CO_ProjectFilePath>..\MySln_Release_AnyCPU.obproj</CO_ProjectFilePath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <CO_ObjFiles Include="ALL MY DLL/EXE HERE">
      <InProject>false</InProject>
    </CO_ObjFiles>
    <CO_BinFiles Include="..ALL MY DLL/EXE HERE">
      <InProject>false</InProject>
    </CO_BinFiles>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="C:\Program Files (x86)\LogicNP Software\Crypto Obfuscator For .Net 2015\CryptoObfuscator.targets" />
```

Build and voila !