# Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json," after obfuscation of a .net exe

Tags: c#, json.net, dsharp+

Error:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: The File or the Assemply "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" is not found  (Exception of HRESULT: 0x80131040)
Filename: "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"
   in DSharpPlus.Net.DiscordApiClient.<GetGatewayInfoAsync>d__122.MoveNext()
```

I guess the problem is DSharpPlus, because I use newtonsoft to get login details from a json file to connect to my login system, therefore the problem is with DSharpPlus. I get this error after obfuscation my programm. I used VMProtect 3.4 Ultimate but every other obfuscator also gives me a error: (for example the open source obfuscator: AsStrongAsFuck)

I hope somebody can help me, I'm trying it since 4 days.

Comment: Does this answer your question ? (you tried for 4 days but you better should have searched, I find this link on my phone while taking a bath) [Trying to obfuscate my project using Crypto broke it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18284123/trying-to-obfuscate-my-project-using-crypto-broke-it) Also read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users